# Relation between projective modules over $R$ and $R[T]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, polynomials, projective-module

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $R[U]$ the polynomial ring in one variable. What is the relation between projective modules over $R$ and projective modules over $R[U]$? Is every projective module over $R[U]$ of the form $P[U]$ for a projective $R$-module $P$? If not what are the obstructions?

Edit: I realised that this question was to general for what I was actually looking for. Since the question in the current form seems to be interesting on its own, I refrained from editing it and opened a [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151214/has-any-finitely-generated-torsion-module-over-a-polynomial-ring-a-finite-resols) instead.

Comment: If your $R[U]$-module is *finitely generated*, then the Quillen-Suslin theorem says that it must be *free*. This actually holds for $R[U_1, \ldots, U_n]$-modules. I don't know about the general case.

Comment: @Leandro: surely one needs some hypothesis such as that the $R[U]$-module is free over $R$.

Comment: Dear Leandro, what you say is  true if $R$ is a field and  false for general commutative rings.

Comment: @Georges,@Qiaochu you're absolutely right. I had the *field* case in mind.

Comment: Just to clarify, the theorem is that a finitely generated projective $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$-module for $k$ a field is free, right?

Comment: Dear @Keenan, yes, that's exactly right. In geometric language this says that all algebraic vector bundles on $\mathbb A^n_k$ are  trivial (analogous to topological vector bundles on $\mathbb R^n$ being trivial, but much more difficult).

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. They made me realise that the question is a) interesting and indeed not trivial b) probably to general for what I actually wanted to know. I thought about editing the question but I guess it's a good thing it is out there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the   answer  for finitely generated modules of rank one.  Recall that the isomorphism classes of these modules form a group, the Picard group $Pic(R)$, with tensor product as multiplication.

> **Theorem (Traverso, Swan)**
>   For a commutative ring $R$ the following are equivalent:
>   a) The reduced ring $R_{red}=R/Nil(R)$ is semi-normal
>   b) The natural group morphism $Pic(R)\stackrel {\cong}{\to} Pic(R[U])$ is an isomorphism ($U=$ indeterminate)

And what does it mean that $R$ is semi-normal?

It means that if $x,y\in  R$ satisfy $y^2=x^3$, then there exists $s\in R$ with $x=s^2$ and $y=s^3$ .
(Geometrically:  you can parametrize the cusp over $R$ ).
Admittedly this condition is a little strange, but at least it is easy to see that a normal ring $R$ (= integrally closed domain) is semi-normal :
   Take $s=\frac {y}{x}\in Frac(R)$. Of course we have $x=s^2$ and $y=s^3$.
 The key point is that $s\in R $ : the fraction  $s=\frac {y}{x}$ is integral over $R$ because it satisfies the monic equation $T^2-x=0$ and since $R$ is integrally closed we must have $s\in R$ .

Comment: That is a nice answer. Unfortunately it is hardly helpful for me (since my question wasn't precise enough, not since the answer wasn't accurate). I'll just wait for a while whether there will be other answers and accept yours if nothing new comes up.

Answer (score 3):

If $R$ is a left regular ring, then the canonical map $K_0(R) \to K_0(R[t])$ is an isomorphism. This result is due to Grothendieck at least when $R$ is commutative. The general case can be found in the paper "The Whitehead group of a polynomial extension" (Bass, Heller, Swan) or in Rosenberg's book on Algebraic K-Theory.

Of course, this does *not* imply that every f.g. projective $R[t]$-module has the form $P[t]$ for some f.g. projective $R$-module (but we cannot expect that!); but this turns out to be true "up to exact sequences".

Comment: Thx, I really should have seen this myself. In fact I am trying to prove a generalised form of the fundamental theorem. And somehow I got lost between what I may assume and what I have to prove...

Comment: Perhaps you can open a new question which is more specific and addresses your generalized form of the fundamental theorem?

Comment: @SimonMarkett Where is your new question? I am curious about it. The link does not work.